# Contract expression of circle segment area contingent on height

Tags: trigonometry, circles, area

I want to determine a function for the area of the segment's height.

I have made it this far, but I would like to contract the equation further - sadly, I do not know how to do this while still keeping h explicit.

$A(h) = \frac{R^2}{2}\left(2\arccos\left(\frac{R-h}{R}\right) - \sin\left(2 \arccos\left(\frac{R-h}{R}\right)\right) \right)$

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

$$\sin{2 \theta} = 2 \sin{\theta} \cos{\theta}$$

so that

$$A(h) = R^2 \left [\arccos{\left (1-\frac{h}{R}\right)} - \left (1-\frac{h}{R}\right) \sqrt{2 \frac{h}{R} - \frac{h^2}{R^2}} \right] $$

Comment: hmmm... many thanks for your input, and I guess the equation _is_ simplified in this form - though I wouldn't say contracted. Is there any way to make it shorter (and reduce the instances of h)?

Comment: @TheChymera: no.